# What is the datatype to store multiselect picklists?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqldatatypes

In a recruitment app, for the application model I'd like to have a multiselect picklist called desired_industry.

I would like to be able to filter users by their desired industries, and to notify users when a new job is created, for their chosen industries.

I'm a bit confused as to how to approach this though.

When I'm making the model, what datatype should I ascribe to it?

If it's a string, how will I go about making sure that I can filter based on the answers, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select users by industries, you can make separate model for the industries which has many-to-many relationship with users model.

Comment: Hi Kirill, this makes sense. In this case, would the multi select options be the only one I would take out from the common_app model? Because I would need to be able to filter users by other options, like for example graduation year, etc. However, the other options only have one value. Or, would you take every option out as a many to many relationship, and string them together in a form?

Comment: You can stack scopes. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391882/writing-scopes-for-many-to-many-relationships